Solidity ZombiCrypto like game on Solana with anchor - zombie owership
I'm learning Solana and as a first project I'm trying to rewrite cryptozombie smart contract in Anchor.
Thats what I came up so far
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_lang::solana_program::clock::Clock;
use std::mem::size_of;

declare_id!("uHnD8BPECQnMXF4vPySb76cDhoZ2mGm4zRX1ukq9n6Q");

#[program]
pub mod zombies_2 {
    use super::*;

    pub fn create_zombie(ctx: Context<CreateZombie>) -> Result<()> {
        let zombie = &mut ctx.accounts.zombie;
        let clock = Clock::get()?;
        let creator_key = ctx.accounts.zombie_creator.key().to_bytes();
        let timestamp = clock.unix_timestamp as u64;

        // Combine creator key and timestamp to generate semi-random DNA
        let mut dna_bytes = Vec::with_capacity(32 + 8);
        dna_bytes.extend(&creator_key);
        dna_bytes.extend(&timestamp.to_le_bytes());

        let hash_bytes = anchor_lang::solana_program::keccak::hash(&dna_bytes).to_bytes();
        zombie.dna = u64::from_le_bytes(
            hash_bytes[..8]
                .try_into()
                .expect("Slice should be 8 bytes long"),
        );
        zombie.owner = ctx.accounts.zombie_creator.key();
        Ok(())
    }

}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateZombie<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = zombie_creator, space = 8 + 32 + 32 + size_of::<Zombie>())]
    pub zombie: Account<'info, Zombie>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub zombie_creator: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}


#[account]
pub struct Zombie {
    pub dna: u64,
    pub owner: Pubkey
}

then in my tests I have
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
const assert = require("assert");

describe("zombie-2", () => {
  const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
  anchor.setProvider(provider);
  const program = anchor.workspace.Zombies2;
  const zombieCreator = provider.wallet.payer;

  it("creates a new zombie", async () => {
    const zombieKeypair = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
    await program.rpc.createZombie({
      accounts: {
        zombie: zombieKeypair.publicKey,
        zombieCreator: zombieCreator.publicKey,
        systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      },
      signers: [zombieKeypair],
    });

    const zombie = await program.account.zombie.fetch(zombieKeypair.publicKey);

    assert.ok(zombie.owner.equals(zombieCreator.publicKey));
  });

It fails the asserting and I struggle to figure out why?
Also is that a right way to structure Zombie ownership? single user should be able to own multiple zombies.

Does this answer your question? How is Token Account Owner Different from Account Owner and Account Holder?

The concept of owner is overloaded in Solana. In the code, you're printing out the program that owns the account, not the owner in the data portion of the account
